# Java security api - Error getting ServerAuthContext by implementing HttpAuthenticationMechanism

Tags: security, authentication, jboss, java-ee-8

Environment:

- Jboss 7.2
- Java 11
- java security api (soteria)

I have an application with many contexts secured with Keycloak and on one of them I implemented a custom HttpAuthenicationMechanism to secure my context. When I deploy the application on the server sometimes worked but other times it do not and it thows Error getting ServerAuthContext for authContextId default-host.

Is there something I am missing?

**server.log**

```
2021-07-12 14:09:22,039 ERROR [org.jboss.security] (default task-5) PBOX00374: Error getting ServerAuthContext for authContextId default-host /app2 and security domain jaspitest: javax.security.auth.message.AuthException
    at org.picketbox//org.jboss.security.auth.message.config.JBossServerAuthConfig.getAuthContext(JBossServerAuthConfig.java:187)
    at org.picketbox//org.jboss.security.plugins.auth.JASPIServerAuthenticationManager.isValid(JASPIServerAuthenticationManager.java:99)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jaspi.JASPICAuthenticationMechanism.authenticate(JASPICAuthenticationMechanism.java:125)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl$AuthAttempter.transition(SecurityContextImpl.java:245)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl$AuthAttempter.access$100(SecurityContextImpl.java:231)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl.attemptAuthentication(SecurityContextImpl.java:125)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl.authTransition(SecurityContextImpl.java:99)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl.authenticate(SecurityContextImpl.java:92)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:55)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:53)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:59)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jaspi.JASPICSecureResponseHandler.handleRequest(JASPICSecureResponseHandler.java:48)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-undertow-adapter@4.8.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.keycloak.adapters.undertow.ServletPreAuthActionsHandler.handleRequest(ServletPreAuthActionsHandler.java:69)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:360)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final-redhat-1//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final-redhat-1//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final-redhat-1//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final-redhat-1//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

**jboss-web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-app>
    <security-domain>jaspitest</security-domain>
</jboss-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in Wildfly versions 13.0.0.Beta1 and 14.0.0.Final when it uses an implementation of HttpAuthenticationMechanism interface with more than one context (ear file with many war's).

Fixed in Wilfly version 15.

[Red Hat - BUG Security API - Soteria - Jaspic - Error getting ServerAuthContext](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/WFLY-10417)

One workaround, it is to separate ear en different instances, one with the context with HttpAuthenticationMecanism and the rest of contexts together.